# through command line automation, create/edit client specification view

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have two directories like:

```
//A/B/C/Folder-One/

//A/B/C/D/Folder-Two/
```

Now, in automation I want to map above these paths to one client and sync it.

like
//A/B/C/Folder-One/ //MYClient/Folder-One/...
//A/B/C/Folder-Two/ //MYClient/Folder-Two/...

Can any one help me how can I achieve that through automation?

Assumption note: In the current directory, I have `.perforce` file where respective variables are configured and `p4 client -o` is also working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--field` undoc option makes this pretty easy:

```
p4 --field "View+=//A/B/C/Folder-One/... //MYClient/Folder-One/..." client -o | p4 client -i
p4 --field "View+=//A/B/C/Folder-Two/... //MYClient/Folder-Two/..." client -o | p4 client -i
```

See `p4 help undoc` and also this blog post: https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/20161-command-line-roundup

Comment: is "--field" option added recently?
~$p4 --field
Perforce client error:
 p4 -h for usage.
 Invalid option: --field.
~$ p4 -V
Perforce - The Fast Software Configuration Management System.
Copyright 1995-2014 Perforce Software.  All rights reserved.
This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project
for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit (http://www.openssl.org/)
See 'p4 help legal' for full OpenSSL license information
Version of OpenSSL Libraries: OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
Rev. P4/MACOSX105X86_64/2014.1/821990 (2014/04/08)

Comment: Per the blog post, note that this was added in the 2016.1 release -- you're currently using the 2014.1 version.  :)